# PHP - broken image displaying from database

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdo

Every time a user submits a picture for their "profile pic" it will display as a "broken image" and I noticed that when I physically insert an image into the mysql data base and display it, it works perfectly and the size of the file changes to "BLOB - KiB" instead of MB. But when I insert that same image into the database using my "upload file", that image turns to "BLOB MB" and doesn't display on the website. I saw some post about this and they said to remove the "addslashes" from the variable and i did that but it still didn't work. So what i wan't to do is display the image from the database that was submitted by the user. It works when you physically insert it into the database without a file but if you do it with one, it doesn't work. Here is a screen shot of the database structure, upload file, and retrieving file.

[image]

PHP Upload file

```
session_start();
if(empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post') { //catch file overload error...
    $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size'); //grab the size limits...
    echo "<p style=\"color: #F00;\">\nPlease note files larger than {$postMax} will result in this error!</p>"; // echo out error and solutions...
    return $postMax;
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
    if($_SESSION['came_from_upload'] != true) {
        setcookie("username", "", time() - 60 * 60);
        $_COOKIE['username'] = "";
        header("Location: developerLogin.php");
        exit;
    }
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $token = $_SESSION['token'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
        $fullname = addslashes(trim($_POST['fullname']));
        $username = addslashes(trim($_POST['username']));
        $email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
        $password = addslashes(trim($_POST['password']));
        $storePassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(
            'cost' => 10
        ));
        $file_tmp = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
        $file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name']));
        try {
            // new php data object 
            $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
            //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
            $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("There was an error connecting to the database");
        }
        $stmtChecker = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE user_id = ?");
        $stmtChecker->execute(array(
            $userid
        ));
        if($result = !$stmtChecker->fetch()) {
            setcookie("username", "", time() - 60 * 60);
            $_COOKIE['username'] = "";
            header("Location: developerLogin.php");
            exit;
        }
        if(!empty($fullname)) {
            $stmtFullname = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET fullname = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmtFullname->execute(array(
                $fullname,
                $userid
            ));
        }
        if(!empty($username)) {
            $stmtCheckerUsername = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE username = ?");
            $stmtCheckerUsername->execute($username);
            if($resultCheckerUsername = $stmtCheckerUsername->fetch()) {
                die("Username Already in use! Please try again");
            }
            $stmtUsername = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET username = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmtUsername->execute(array(
                $username,
                $userid
            ));
        }
        if(!empty($email)) {
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) {
                die("Email is Not Valid!");
            }
            $stmtCheckerEmail = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE email = ?");
            $stmtCheckerEmail->execute($email);
            if($resultCheckerEmail = $stmtCheckerEmail->fetch()) {
                die("Email Already in use! Please try again");
            }
            $stmtEmail = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET email = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmtEmail->execute(array(
                $email,
                $userid
            ));
        }
        if(!empty($password)) {
            if(strlen($password) < 6) {
                die("Password has to be GREATER than 6 characters!");
            }
            //Check if password has atleast ONE Uppercase, One Lowercase and a number
            if(!preg_match("(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$)", $password)) {
                echo 'Password needs to be at least ONE uppercase, ONE lowercase, and a number!';
                exit;
            }
            $stmtPassword = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET password = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmtPassword->execute(array(
                $storePassword,
                $userid
            ));
        }
        if($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $mime = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            if(strstr($mime, "video/")) {
                die("Please note that this file is NOT an image... Please select an image for your Profile Picture");
            } else if(strstr($mime, "image/")) {
                $allowedTypes = array(
                    IMAGETYPE_PNG,
                    IMAGETYPE_JPEG
                );
                $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                if($extensionCheck = !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes)) {
                    die("Failed to upload image; the format is not supported");
                }
                $dir = "devFiles/";
                $uploadedFile = $dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
                if(is_dir($dir) == false) {
                    mkdir($dir, 0700);
                }
                if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile)) {
                    die("There was an error moving the file... Please try again later!");
                }
                $stmtFile = $handler->prepare("UPDATE generalusersdata SET profile_image = ?, file_tmp = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
                $stmtFile->execute(array(
                    $file_name,
                    $file_tmp,
                    $userid
                ));
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        header("Location: developerUpload.php");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: developerLogin.php");
    exit;
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    Information Changer<br>
    Fullname: <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name.....">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name.....">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email.....">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Password: <label><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password....." ></label>
    <br></br>
    Profile Picture: <input type="file" name="file">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Retrieving file

```
try {
    // new php data object
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
    //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception 
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("There was an error connecting to the database");
}
$stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM generalusersdata WHERE user_id = :userid");
$stmt->bindValue(':userid', '61', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
while($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($result['file_tmp']) . '"/>';
}
```

Comment: You're using prepared statements with placeholder values, which is the proper way to do it, but you're also adding `addslashes` on top of that which will mangle your data and break things.That method should not be used in this code, it just causes chaos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing the temporay **filename** - not its contents.

```
$file_tmp = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

Should be

```
$file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: Ohhh wow i thought that was the way you store the content. Thank you and if i can ask another quick question, when i use "getPath()" for the "directoryIterator" and echo it, it gives me the actual path of an image in the directory. But i want to take the image not the path and submit to database. Is that possible?

Comment: Oh so i just get the path and set it equal to a variable like "$test = file_get_contents($path)" ?and then submit into database?

Comment: Yep, when storing an image to a database you are actually storing the contents of the image-file. So you need a way to retrieve that contents (where `file_get_contents` is the most convenient way).

Comment: I am trying it for my other upload file but its not working, for this one i have a "for loop" and when i put "$file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])[$key];" it gives me an error "file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given"